# JPA OneToOne Mapping On Partial Primary Keys Column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have two tables as described below:

```
+-------------------+        +------------------------+        
| TB_CONFIG         |        | TB_CONFIG_LANG         |        
+-------------------+        +------------------------+        
| Customer_Id  (PK) |        | Product_Id         (PK)|        
| Company_Id   (PK) |        | Config_Id          (PK)|        
| Product_Id   (PK) |        | Language_Id        (PK)|        
| Config_Id    (PK) |        | Config_Description     |        
| Config_Value      |        | Config_Hint            |        
+-------------------+        | Config_Help            |   
                             +------------------------+
```

`TB_CONFIG` data is about 'configurations' that was set by a specified 'Customer' and 'Company' on a 'Product (solution)' that we have.

`TB_CONFIG_LANG` stores data about the Description, Hint and Help of all configurations that we have on various languages, like 'EN_US', 'PT_BR', and so on.

We always will have the language to be passed as a parameter to the `JPQL` that will be used to load data, but I can't realize the 'proper way' to map this join...

Actually, these tables are mapped as below:

**TB_CONFIG_LANG Primary Key**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
public class PkConfigurationLang implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String configId;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String languageId;

}
```

**TB_CONFIG_LANG Table**

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "CLOUD_CATALOG", name = "TB_CONFIG_LANG")
@Cache(region = "oConfigurationsCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ConfigurationLanguage {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PkConfigurationLang id;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_DESCRIPTION")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_HINT")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_HELP")
    private String help;

}
```

**TB_CONFIG Primary Key**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
public class PkConfiguration implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int customerId;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int companyId;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int productId;    
    
    @Column(name = "CONFIG_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String configId;

}
```

**TB_CONFIG Table**

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "CLOUD_CATALOG", name = "TB_CONFIG")
@Cache(region = "oConfigurationsCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Configuration {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PkConfiguration id;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_VALUE")
    private String configValue;

}
```

My first attempt was to map a `@OneToOne` relationship one `Configuration` class, like this:

**TB_CONFIG Table With OneToOne relationship**

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "CLOUD_CATALOG", name = "TB_CONFIG")
@Cache(region = "oConfigurationsCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Configuration {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PkConfiguration id;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_VALUE")
    private String configValue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONFIG_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ConfigurationLanguage language;

}
```

And Write a JPQL Like this:

```
TypedQuery<ConfigurationCompany> query = manager.createQuery("select c from ConfigurationCompany c " +
        "join c.language l " +
        "where c.id.customerId = :customerId " +
        "and c.id.companyId = :companyId " +
        "and c.id.productId = :productId " +
        "and c.id.configId = :configId " +
        "and l.id.languageId = :languageId", ConfigurationCompany.class);
```

But I received the following exception while trying to run the application:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: referencedColumnNames(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_ID) of com.mycompany.api.configuration.domain.model.ConfigurationCompany.language referencing com.mycompany.api.configuration.domain.model.ConfigurationLanguage not mapped to a single property; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_NAME) of com.mycompany.api.configuration.domain.model.ConfigurationCompany.language referencing com.mycompany.api.configuration.domain.model.ConfigurationLanguage not mapped to a single property
```

And I think that this is because I'm not referencing the Language_Id column while creating the `@OneToOne` mapping...

So, the question is:
Is this the properly way to achieve this kind of relationship? If yes, what Am I missing?
If not, how could I properly configure this mapping?

Hint:
I can't change the database schema.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `TB_CONFIG_LANG`  does not have a column `CONFIG_NAME` but you use it in `@JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_NAME", referenc...`

Comment: @DirkDeyne, I'm sorry... It was a mistake while writing the question... The correct name is CONFIG_ID

Answer (score 0):

A one-to-one mapping like this is AFAIK not supported by Hibernate. Apart from that, it's not safe to do this, unless you have a unique key defined for `TB_CONFIG(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_ID)` and `TB_CONFIG_LANG(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_ID)`. What's wrong with using a `@OneToMany` assocation for this like:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONFIG_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Set<ConfigurationLanguage> languages;
```

This way, you only need a unique key for `TB_CONFIG_LANG(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_ID)`. To avoid that as well, you need to use a map:

```
@OneToMany
@MapKeyColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONFIG_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Map<String, ConfigurationLanguage> languages;
```

But note that this is still not safe from a DB perspective. A foreign key must always refer to a unique key. So either you put the `Company_Id` and `Customer_Id` into the `TB_CONFIG_LANG` as well or you remove these two from the primary key of `TB_CONFIG`

Comment: Hello @Christian, thanks a lot! That was one of the approached that I tried, but with the same error. The only thing that worked was removing the LANGUAGE_ID column from the PK, but I thinks that this isn't the correct approach since the model is not reflecting what is on the database...

Comment: What error do you get? I am using similar approaches in many projects and it works fine for me

Comment: I got the error: referencedColumnNames(PRODUCT_ID, CONFIG_ID) of TB_CONFIG_LANG referencing TB_CONFIG not mapped to a single property